# Are these series equal? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(a_{2n-1}+a_{2n})}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Is it true that these two series are equal?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(a_{2n-1}+a_{2n})}$$

If I write them out I get

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n} = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(a_{2n-1}+a_{2n})} = (a_1 + a_2) + (a_3 + a_4) + \cdots$$

It seems to me like they're equal. I am given that $a_n \rightarrow 0$ and asked to prove that this implies the first converges if and only if the second does as well.

Comment: Great question. I see there is already an answer but I thought I would give a simple example: let $a_1 = 1, a_2 = -1, a_3 = 2, a_4 = -2, \ldots, a_{2n-1} = n, a_{2n}= -n$. Then the second sum is zero while the first does not converge. The order of summation matters sometimes. A related (but slightly different) concept is absolute vs. conditional convergence. If a sum converges absolutely, you can rearrange it as you please and it will always converge to the same thing; however, the same is not true of conditionally convergent sums like $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

Comment: @User8128 I found your comment is quite illustrative as related to the present situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\sum a_n$ converges, then yes; the partial sums of $\sum a_{2n-1}+a_{2n}$ are a subsequence of the partial sums of $\sum a_n$.

On the other hand, if $\sum a_{2n - 1} + a_{2n}$ converges **and** $a_{2n+1} \rightarrow 0$, then $\sum a_n$ converges, as the partial sums of $\sum a_n$ are either equal to a partial sum of $\sum a_{2n - 1} + a_{2n}$ or differ by an odd term of the sequence $a_n$, which tends to $0$ by assumption.

I'll leave you to think of a counterexample when $a_{2n+1} \not\rightarrow 0$.